# Good software for solving a system of algebraic equations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, mathematical-software

I need to solve the following system of equations. solve([

a*c*e=a2*c2*e2,
b*d*f=t*b2*d2*f2,
t*a1*c1*e1=a3*c3*e3,
b1*d1*f1=b3*d3*f3,

a*b*a1*b1=a2*b2*a3*b3,
c*d*c1*d1=c2*d2*c3*d3,
e*f*e1*f1=e2*f2*e3*f3,

b+c=b2+c2,
d+e=d2+e2,
b1+c1=b3+c3,
d1+e1=d3+e3,

a1*b1*(b + c) + c*d*(b1 + c1) =
a3*b3*(b + c) + c2*d2*(b1 + c1),

c1*d1*(d + e) + e*f*(d1 + e1) =
c3*d3*(d + e) + e2*f2*(d1 + e1)

], 
[a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2,a3,b3,c3,d3,e3,f3], IgnoreSpecialCases,VectorFormat);

I tried to use some software to solve it. I can only solve it in the cases that most of a,b,c,d,e,f,a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1 are given by some numbers. Are there some good software which can solve this system of equations symbolically? Thank you very much.

Comment: If you look at the "Related Questions" down the side of this page, you may find some where there have been answers you would find helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Maple command $$sol := SolveTools:-PolynomialSystem({a*c*e = a2*c2*e2, b*d*f = t*b2*d2*f2, b1*d1*f1 = b3*d3*f3, a*b*a1*b1 = a2*b2*a3*b3, c*d*c1*d1 = c2*d2*c3*d3, e*f*e1*f1 = e2*f2*e3*f3, t*a1*c1*e1 = a3*c3*e3, b+c = b2+c2, b1+c1 = b3+c3, d+e = d2+e2, d1+e1 = d3+e3, a1*b1*(b+c)+c*d*(b1+c1) = a3*b3*(b+c)+c2*d2*(b1+c1), c1*d1*(d+e)+e*f*(d1+e1) = c3*d3*(d+e)+e2*f2*(d1+e1)}, {a2, a3, b2, b3, c2, c3, d2, d3, e2, e3, f2, f3}): $$ produces a long output which consists of $12$ elements. For example, the first one is  $a2$ equals a rational function of the $13$ free variables $ a, a1, a2, b, b1, c, c1, d, d1, e, e1, f, t $ of degree $17$. The others are similar. See the Maple output here https://www.dropbox.com/s/a8t6z5u2ukf0wt6/system.pdf as an exported PDF file. [The PolynomialSystem](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=SolveTools)  command uses [the Groebner basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis) tools.